# Blazor 8 (Server only) IIS hosting behind reverse proxy (YARP)

Tags: asp.net, blazor

In a new Blazor 8 Web App using the new Authentication system, it is possible for me to run behind a reverse proxy (YARP) via Visual Studio, but the same code deployed in a Local IIS fails at login attempt with a 400 Bad Request

[image]

There seems to be nowhere that can give an insight to why this is (logs, dev tools, Window Event Viewer)

Tried disabling Antiforgery tokens with attribute but still no luck (+ in the request validation tokens are present)

Anyone successfully gotten Blazor Fullstack to work on IIS with reverse proxy or have a clue how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: does everything work when not using YARP?

Comment: Yes, without Yarp, deployed on the IIS things work